# Is there a way to auto sum the return of concatenated countifs?

Tags: google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to calculate a total using auto sum. I don't know how to take the `countif` data to use in an auto sum formula when there are more than one.

The `countif`s calculate the occurrence of a fixed set of categories select-able through a drop-down menu with data validation. Because in my case there are 5 options the final calculation cell has 5 `countif`s. However, there are 5 columns with the same setup and I want to be able to total the data.

```
=CONCATENATE("Jeans: "&COUNTIF(J19:J29, "Jeans"), " " ,"C&J: "&
 COUNTIF(J18:J29, "Coats & Jackets"), " " ,"Tops: "&
 COUNTIF(J18:J29, "Tops"), " " ,"Drs: "&
 COUNTIF(J18:J29, "Dresses & Skirts"), " " ,"Acs: "&
 COUNTIF(J18:J29, "Accessories"))
```

The return for the above code looks like:

```
Jeans: 0 C&J: 0 Tops: 0 Drs: 0 Acs: 0
```

Simply adding the cells together has not worked. Right now I am trying to figure out how to pull each value.

Adding all 5 columns together I expect to have something like:

```
Month total: Jeans: 30 C&J: 12 Tops: 45 Drs: 4 Acs: 10
```

Eventually, I would like to be able to add each total together for a grand total.

[image: example with highlighted areas to illustrate explanation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=CONCATENATE("Month total: Jeans: "&
 INDEX(QUERY({SPLIT(LOWER(A1),"jeansctopsdra :&");
              SPLIT(LOWER(B1),"jeansctopsdra :&");
              SPLIT(LOWER(C1),"jeansctopsdra :&");
              SPLIT(LOWER(D1),"jeansctopsdra :&");
              SPLIT(LOWER(E1),"jeansctopsdra :&")},
 "select sum(Col1),sum(Col2),sum(Col3),sum(Col4),sum(Col5) 
  label sum(Col1)'',sum(Col2)'',sum(Col3)'',sum(Col4)'',sum(Col5)''",0),1,1)&
 " C&J: "&
 INDEX(QUERY({SPLIT(LOWER(A1),"jeansctopsdra :&");
              SPLIT(LOWER(B1),"jeansctopsdra :&");
              SPLIT(LOWER(C1),"jeansctopsdra :&");
              SPLIT(LOWER(D1),"jeansctopsdra :&");
              SPLIT(LOWER(E1),"jeansctopsdra :&")},
 "select sum(Col1),sum(Col2),sum(Col3),sum(Col4),sum(Col5) 
  label sum(Col1)'',sum(Col2)'',sum(Col3)'',sum(Col4)'',sum(Col5)''",0),1,2)&
 " Tops: "&
 INDEX(QUERY({SPLIT(LOWER(A1),"jeansctopsdra :&");
              SPLIT(LOWER(B1),"jeansctopsdra :&");
              SPLIT(LOWER(C1),"jeansctopsdra :&");
              SPLIT(LOWER(D1),"jeansctopsdra :&");
              SPLIT(LOWER(E1),"jeansctopsdra :&")},
 "select sum(Col1),sum(Col2),sum(Col3),sum(Col4),sum(Col5) 
  label sum(Col1)'',sum(Col2)'',sum(Col3)'',sum(Col4)'',sum(Col5)''",0),1,3)&
 " Drs: "&
 INDEX(QUERY({SPLIT(LOWER(A1),"jeansctopsdra :&");
              SPLIT(LOWER(B1),"jeansctopsdra :&");
              SPLIT(LOWER(C1),"jeansctopsdra :&");
              SPLIT(LOWER(D1),"jeansctopsdra :&");
              SPLIT(LOWER(E1),"jeansctopsdra :&")},
 "select sum(Col1),sum(Col2),sum(Col3),sum(Col4),sum(Col5) 
  label sum(Col1)'',sum(Col2)'',sum(Col3)'',sum(Col4)'',sum(Col5)''",0),1,4)&
 " Acs: "&
 INDEX(QUERY({SPLIT(LOWER(A1),"jeansctopsdra :&");
              SPLIT(LOWER(B1),"jeansctopsdra :&");
              SPLIT(LOWER(C1),"jeansctopsdra :&");
              SPLIT(LOWER(D1),"jeansctopsdra :&");
              SPLIT(LOWER(E1),"jeansctopsdra :&")},
 "select sum(Col1),sum(Col2),sum(Col3),sum(Col4),sum(Col5) 
  label sum(Col1)'',sum(Col2)'',sum(Col3)'',sum(Col4)'',sum(Col5)''",0),1,5))
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you explain a little bit about what part is doing? I tried popping it in and changing all the cell values to mine but kept getting an error.

Comment: @ConstantFun sure. long story short we have 5 identical columns which differ only in numbers (amounts) and we need to output one sentence with summed up amounts, so: first step is to get rid off words so we could sum up numbers. so we call LOWER and eliminate these characters (jeansctopsdra :&) in all five columns (A1,B1,C1,D1,E1) and we SPLIT each cell into 5 virtual cells eg. we create kinda virtual table of matrix 5x5 cells (5 items in cell multiplied by 5 cells). this virtual table is then processed  by QUERY where each column is summed up and the result of each virtual column is then

Comment: INDEXed out so we would have 5 virtual chunks of summed up values. then these chunks are CONCATENATEed to create one final sentence.

Comment: Thank you @player0 To achieve a yearly total I could essentially use the same technique and update the cell values? And then, add the required additional months as `INDEX` blocks until I had 12 blocks representing each month?

Comment: @ConstantFun in essence yes. virtual table shall be of matrix 5x12 (5items * 12 months) eg. instead of 5x SPLITx per INDEX chunk you will do 12x SPLITs per each of 5 INDEX chunks.